# What is a "problem matcher" in compound tasks?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

The [documentation for compound tasks](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_compound-tasks) states that for compound tasks that have a `dependsOn` entry,

> (...) Any background/watch tasks used in `dependsOn` with `"dependsOrder": "sequence"` must have a problem matcher that tracks when they are "done".

What does this mean, exactly?

The example does not mention this "problem matcher" and I tried to make a sequence of tasks running in a `shell` mode without such "problem matches" and they ran sequentially as expected.

Comment: are they really watch tasks and does it work when you run the main task a second time

Comment: @rioV8: aahhh, thanks. No, my tasks are neither background nor watch tasks (my eyes skipped through these words ...). So it is normal that they work sequentially. Still, is there documentation for the "problem matcher" in case they are indeed watch ones?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_background-watching-tasks

Comment: you can't wait till the PID of the task disappears because the task is always alive, so you need a PM with an `endsPattern`